# Defining a reusable template for views in react-admin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

Using `react-admin` I have an `EditView` like this:

```
export const LanguageEdit = props => (
  <Edit title="Edit: Language" {...props}>
    <SimpleForm>
      <TextInput source="name" label="Name" />
      <TextInput source="iso1" label="ISO-1" />
      <TextInput source="iso2" label="ISO-2" />
    </SimpleForm>
  </Edit>
);
```

My application will have several of these edit views, each with a different content in the `<SimpleForm>` element. The title however will differ only slightly in the different views.

`<Edit title="Edit: Language" {...props}>`
`<Edit title="Edit: City" {...props}>`
`<Edit title="Edit: Country" {...props}>`

Is there some way to define this as a "template" which will then be used in all the edit views?

**Template**

```
<Edit title="Edit: ${currentViewName}" {...props}>
  <SimpleForm>
    ${somePlaceholder}
  </SimpleForm>
</Edit>
```

**View content (pseudo code)**

```
currentViewName = "Country";
somePlaceholder => (
          <TextInput source="name" label="Name" />
          <TextInput source="iso1" label="ISO-1" />
          <TextInput source="iso2" label="ISO-2" />
);
applyTemplate(currentViewName, somePlaceholder);
```

Comment: do you want to provide props of `Edit` in this `applyTemplate()`

Comment: Actually, yes. the props which are currently provided with `export const LanguageEdit = props => (`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the Edit component like:

```
const EditTemplate = ({ title, children, ...props }) => (
    <Edit title={`Edit: ${title}`} {...props}>
        <SimpleForm>
            {children}
        </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>
)
```

And use it as a normal Edit view:

```
export const LanguageEdit = props => (
  <EditTemplate title="Language" {...props}>
      <TextInput source="name" label="Name" />
      <TextInput source="iso1" label="ISO-1" />
      <TextInput source="iso2" label="ISO-2" />
  </EditTemplate>
);
```

Comment: That's what I'm looking for. One more thing: Instead of `title={\`Edit: ${title}\`` I'd like to include another tag which shall be evaluated later. The result should look like this: `<Edit title={<EditTitle />} {...props}>`

Comment: Great, you can use `React.cloneElement(element, props)` to do what you want. There is a lot of example in React Admin codebase if you need.